# How to handle stream down error in chat application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, meteor

I am using METEOR DDPSubscription for creating the messaging stream, When I am sending messages continuously and then I see the following error,

```
subscribe(eventName, args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (this.subscriptions[eventName]) {
            return resolve();
        }
        const subscription = Tracker.nonreactive(() => this.ddpConnection.subscribe(
            this.subscriptionName,
            eventName,
            { useCollection: this.useCollection, args },
            {
                onStop: () => reject(this.unsubscribe(eventName)),
                onReady: resolve
            }
        ));
        this.subscriptions[eventName] = { subscription };
    })
}
```

From the above code, I am getting error at the following line,

```
onStop: () => reject(this.unsubscribe(eventName)),
```

So I decided to add timeout at regular intervals as follows,

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!subscriptionQuery.data) {
        return;
    }

    UserAction.addStream(rid);
    return (): void => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            UserAction.cancel(rid);
        }, 2000);
    };
}, [rid, subscriptionQuery.data]);
```

Can anyone suggest am I doing in the right way. Thanks.